# Range in excel formula in terms of cell and row index

Tags: vba, excel

on a cell I can have formula like this, to check if that cell value is number or not -:

```
=IsNumber(C8)
```

But what if I want to use like this -:

```
 = isNumber(rowINdex,columnIndex)
```

I mean to say, in formula, I want to provide range using rowIndex and columnIndex.  How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use combination of ADDRESS and INDEX.
ADDRESS defines cell name (string) by calling row and column.
INDEX uses this cell name to get the value

your =IsNumber(C8) would look like:

```
=ISNUMBER(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(8;3)))
```

Comment: Thanks.. it is working- just one change - =ISNUMBER(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(8,4)))    (, instead of ;)

Comment: welcome. yeah, I didn't notice the comma, I use different system settings :)

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged VBA - so not sure if you were looking for a VBA solution to this.

Just for clarity though, you can perform the `ISNUMBER` function within VBA, using the row and column index with the [`Cells` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567.aspx).

```
Range("A1").formula = "=ISNUMBER(" & Cells(RowIndex, columnIndex).Address & ")"
```